# change colors in image

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, core-graphics

In my app I use QR code. So I have library that make me UIImage with QR code. This image like default QR

[image]

So I need delete white color (make transparent), and change black to white. Finally I must have white transparent QR

[image]

What the best decision for this?

Answer (score 0):

with gimp you can set the white color to transparent

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC5vdKuwTp0

Comment: I need do it programmatically